# Automating PDF Flowchart to creation of chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

So we currently are creating chatbots using Google DialogFlow. The chatbots that we create are usually decision tree type chatbots that ask a particular question based on the response provided by the user. The client usually sends us flowcharts in pdf which has the decision tree and we then translate it towards creating the said chatbot and adding the relevant modules based on the information provided. Is there a way wherein I can automate some part of the chatbot creation process directly based on the decision tree sent in the PDF? The frequent updates sent by the client is a bit cumbersome so was thinking of automating it.

What I'm thinking currently is somehow converting the PDF file to some JSON format and then using that JSON file, somehow automate the process. I'm a new joiner in the company and they have given me this task to think about.

Comment: Can you explain more about typical flowchart file, what data does actually carry out this pdf file? Can you share the structure?

Comment: It's kind of a decision tree where questions are asked to the user and based on the answer provided, a new question is asked. So the diamond boxes for questions and the rectangular boxes when the chatbot displays something. Question types are either yes/no questions or single select questions so the appropriate branch is selected in the flowchart based on the answer.

Comment: The question here is how would you plan to OCR the flowchart graphs in PDF to robust JSON, as generally Dialogflow offers  [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview)  service where you can handle typical agent creation via specific request [form](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/Agent)?

Comment: Yes, that's totally correct.

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible to automate the creation process of your Dialogflow agent, however, you’ll have to create your own implementation for it. As you’ve mentioned, you can convert the PDF file into a JSON object using your own implementation, then you can use the JSON object as a reference to construct the Request Body of the methods stated below.

If you are using **Dialogflow ES**, then you can use one of Dialogflow ES’s [Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/overview) or APIs ([REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest) / [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc)) to create agents programmatically.

You can create ES Agents with the following methods:

- REST API: [projects.setAgent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/setAgent) method
- RPC API: [SetAgent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.SetAgent-table) method
- [Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/overview): you can look into the documentation of each of the supported languages

After you create an ES agent, you can also add [Intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/create), [Entity Types](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/create), [Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.contexts/create), etc. programmatically to manage your agent’s conversation flows.

If you are using **Dialogflow CX**, then you can use one of Dialogflow CX’s [Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview) or APIs ([REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1-overview) / [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1)) to create agents programmatically.

You can create CX Agents with the following methods:

- REST API: [projects.locations.agents.create](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents/create) method
- RPC API: [CreateAgent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1.Agents.CreateAgent) method
- [Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview): you can look into the documentation of each of the supported languages

After you create a CX agent, you can also add [Intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents.intents/create), [Entity Types](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents.entityTypes/create), [Flows](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents.flows/create), [Webhooks](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents.webhooks/create) etc. programmatically to manage your agent’s conversation flows.

Additionally, note that your JSON Request Body must be formatted correctly based on the Resource that you’re trying to create. For example:

- If you’re trying to create an **ES Agent**, make sure to follow the [Request Body](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/Agent) format.
- If you’re trying to create a **CX Agent**, make sure to follow the [Request Body](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/projects.locations.agents#Agent) format.

Comment: Thanks, I can definitely try the steps that you have recommended.